# Why does this RotateTransform not work programmatically?

Tags: wpf, rotatetransform

I want to create a button control which allows its content to be rotated. My class looks like this. The ApplyRotation does get called but the text remains horizontal.

Have I forgotten something? Invalidate layout or something similar...

```
public class KeyButton : Button
{
    private TextBlock content;
    private Viewbox viewbox;

    #region DEPENDENCY - Angle
    // Dependency Property
    public static readonly DependencyProperty AngleProperty =
         DependencyProperty.Register("Angle", typeof(double),
            typeof(KeyButton),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(0.0, OnAnglePropertyChanged, OnCoerceAngleProperty),
          OnValidateAngleProperty);

    // .NET Property wrapper
    public double Angle
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(AngleProperty); }
        set { SetValue(AngleProperty, value); }
    }

    private static void OnAnglePropertyChanged(DependencyObject source, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        KeyButton control = source as KeyButton;
        if (control != null)
        {
            ApplyRotation(control);
        }
    }

    private static object OnCoerceAngleProperty(DependencyObject sender, object data)
    {
        // TODO implement
        return data;
    }

    private static bool OnValidateAngleProperty(object data)
    {
        // TODO implement validation
        return data is double;
    }
    #endregion

    public KeyButton()
    {
        viewbox = new Viewbox();
        content = new TextBlock { Text = "X" };
        this.Content = viewbox;
        viewbox.Child = content;
    }

    private static void ApplyRotation(KeyButton control)
    {
        if (control.viewbox.Child != null)
        {
            control.viewbox.Child.RenderTransform = new RotateTransform(control.Angle);
        }
    }

    protected override void OnPropertyChanged(System.Windows.DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {

        base.OnPropertyChanged(e);
        switch (e.Property.Name)
        {
            case "Content":
                content.Text = e.NewValue.ToString();
                ApplyRotation(this);
                break;
            default:
                try
                {
                    viewbox.SetValue(e.Property, e.NewValue);
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                }
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

I tried it using XAML at it worked fine. (I have about 100 buttons so I thought it would be better to make a new class...)

```
<Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">
    <Viewbox>
        <TextBlock Text="Hello">
            <TextBlock.RenderTransform>
                <RotateTransform Angle="45"/>
            </TextBlock.RenderTransform>
        </TextBlock>
    </Viewbox>
</Button>
```

Comment: Is the Rotation different for all Button or does it change during runtime?

Comment: I have only applied an angle to one button and it has no effect. The set property method is only called one time with the new angle (45°) but the text remains horizontal...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that when the Content property of your KeyButton is set in XAML like below

```
<KeyButton Content="Hello"/>
```

the Viewbox that you assigned in the contructor is replaced by the new content object. Your overridden OnPropertyChanged method does not prevent that. Your `viewbox` member is then no longer contained in the Content property and the assignment

```
control.viewbox.Child.RenderTransform = new RotateTransform(...)
```

has no visible effect since `control.viewbox` is not visible anymore.

As long as you have the same rotation angle for all your Buttons, i strongly suggest to modify the ContentTemplate in a default Button style as Erno has shown.

Answer (score 0):

You could still go the XAML way:

```
<Style TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Viewbox>
                    <ContentPresenter>
                        <ContentPresenter.RenderTransform>
                            <RotateTransform Angle="45"/>
                        </ContentPresenter.RenderTransform>
                    </ContentPresenter>
                </Viewbox>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: sure - I know it works. I just wnated to save myself some typing and open the possiblity of adding more stuff to the control via the class. As I said, there are a lot of buttons...

Comment: @paul You would have to write this only once, in the default style of the Button.

Comment: But what if someone puts an image in the button... That is why you should use a ContentPresenter

Comment: But you can't change this during runtime, which defeats the point, no?

Comment: @austinwbryan That was not a requirement,  the requirement was to save typing.